# Python: Changes in class instance are not kept after the end of a function

Tags: python, class, oop

I have this code structure:

```
class1 = Class1()

class2 = Class2(class1)
```

class2 has a method called callback, that receives commands via TCP, and depending on them, it tries to change stuff on class1.

Inside of callback, I change stuff using:

```
self.class1.value = new_value
```

If I check self.class1.value inside of callback method, the result is, correctly, new_value. But as soon as I go out of callback (for example, if I check inside of class1, the value is not updated and it goes back to the one before callback was executed.

I checked the instances and are correctly assigned, it's like inside of callback, a copy of class1 is copied before being changed and is changed only locally inside of the method.

Any idea or hint?

Comment: I think you need to show some more relevant code.

Comment: are you using multiprocessing?

Comment: Definitely need more code. First thing I'd look at based on the description is `Class2`'s `__init__`

Comment: @HugoWalter I'm using! I didn't think about it. callback is executed in a different thread because it needs to be listening for new commands in real time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use mutlithreading instead of multiprocessing, since threads share the state while processes each have their own copy of everything (via fork())